# Use jQuery to detect the existence of an element added by native AJAX with creating a loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory-management, settimeout, infinite-loop

I have an issue with a website which uses jQuery and native JS together.

I am trying to add the jQuery UI datepicker to an input which is added to the page using native AJAX. My issue is that the jQuery is running before the AJAX is adding the div to the page.

I can easily fix this using the following code but I don't want the jQuery to constantly check for the existing of the element on pages where it will never exist. I'm worried that this will consume a huge amount of memory? Does the setTimeout function consume memory if it is checking endlessly for the existence of an element?

Any advice or a solution would be fantastic.

Cheers

```
(function() {
    window.main = window.main || {};

    /*
     * Initialisation function
     */
    main.init = function() {
        main.datePicker();
    },


    /*
     * Datepicker function
     */
    main.datePicker = function () {
        // If the input is visible / has loaded do the datepicker function
        var datePickerInput = $('.datepicker');
        if(datePickerInput.is(':visible')) {
            datePickerInput.datepicker({
                minDate         : 0,
                dateFormat      : "dd/mm/yy",
                showOn          : "button",
                buttonImage     : "images/jquery-ui/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly : true,
                buttonText      : "Select date"
            });
        // otherwise recall the function
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() { main.datePicker(); }, 2000);
        } 
    }
})();


// Initialise
$(document).ready(function() {
    main.init();
});
```

Comment: _website which uses jQuery and native JS together_ is jQuery able to work without native JS? :)

Comment: No, it isn't. I mean lots of native JS code plus jQuery code working together. Both carrying out different jobs etc.

Comment: have you tried, adding the main.init() call to the ajax success event?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained, the main.init call contains many other jQuery functions too, for the whole website....so I don't think that would be ideal. Could I not call main.datepicker(); in the ajax success event instead?

Comment: That is what I did and it fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add main.datePicker(); to the ajax success event.